# 13.10 image burn issue

Tags: system-installation, 13.10, dvd, burning

I downloaded the Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit release to burn to a DVD on my Windows 7 machine, and then install on an old XP machine. I am having trouble writing the image to a DVD with this error:

```
The disc image didn't burn successfully because an error occurred (Error Code: 0x080004005)
```

Every time I used the Windows image burner on Windows 7 and I have also tried an external burner with no luck.

From what I have read, the DVD doesn't need to be formatted correctly.

Is there something simple I am overlooking?

Comment: you can use image burners like nero burning rom or any other dvd burners like winiso

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... It seems to be a problem with windows image burner.

I may recommend you two alternative ways to preceed:

a) Change your burning software. Could be Nero burning rom, or other of your preference. In my time on windows the burnings with the embedded software often gave me random problems. My first choice will be the open-source solid as a rock http://www.imgburn.com/ or if you want to check for more, you might be interested in this article: http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-cd-dvd-burning-software.htm

or b) Don't burn it in a DVD! The dvd burning is really old-fashioned. You may find several positive sidekicks on creating a **bootable usb** drive: you will **avoid reading errors** because of the disc or the disc-reader failure, **it's a LOT faster**, and finally **you have the possibility to write data on the disc** (which is a super handy feature when you run a live session to install Ubuntu). Check this section of Ubuntu's website if you choose this way: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: OK I tried ImgBurn and am now receiving a message stating that the layouts do not match. I am using the "write image file to disc".

Comment: @Otterman are you able to burn successfully other disc images?